# How to test if dataset follows zipf's law? (using a Plot in R, tikz or even Python)

Tags: python, r, plot, tikz

I have a very simple problem which I can't solve by myself: I have a small dataset of counts and I want to compare their distribution with zipf's law.
my data is a simple table with one row:

```
31,
29,
28,
27,
27,
27,
27,
26,
25,
24,
23,
23,
22,
22,
22,
21,
21,
20,
20,
20,
19,
19,
19,
18,
18,
18,
18,
17,
17,
17,
17,
16,
15,
15,
15,
15,
14,
14,
13,
13,
13,
13,
12,
12,
12,
12,
11,
11,
11,
10,
10,
9,
8,
8,
8,
7,
7,
7,
6,
6,
6,
6,
6,
5,
5,
5,
4,
3,
2,
2,
2,
2,
1,
1,
```

could anyone help me with this? 
I have tried the hole day…

Comment: Consider defining Zipf's law.  From a quick Google search I suggest looking at the zipfR package.

Comment: I wanna do something like this: http://chengjun.github.io/en/2014/03/fit-power-law/ or that http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7450/how-to-estimate-parameters-for-zipf-truncated-distribution-from-a-data-sample  – I just want to plot the frequency my counts and compare it with the zipf or the Pareto distribution

Comment: i tried zipfR, which seems usefull – but it didn't work (it didn't installed fully, so parts are missing) – And I think i have to convert my data into a spc-file
what is a frequency spectrum ?

Comment: some posts at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180793/how-to-verify-if-data-follows-zipfs-law-without-looking-at-the-graph should help you

Comment: @bhamadicharef: Thanks!!!

Comment: If you use MATLAB there are few examples on FileExchange section one useful one on “Power Law, Exponential and Logarithmic Fit”